# How to assign a variable in the WHERE clause of a sub-query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    Total_Males, SETTLEMENT_ID, URI, _PARENT_AURI    
FROM
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(t2.SEX) as Total_Males, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID, t1.URI, 
         t2._PARENT_AURI 
     FROM 
         PScData t1 
     INNER JOIN 
         PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
     WHERE 
         t1.SETTLEMENT_ID = '11102002002001' 
         AND t2.SEX = '1'
     GROUP BY 
         t1.URI, t2._PARENT_AURI, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID) tmp
```

This is the query that I have written. In the `WHERE` clause, where I have given the exact value - '11102002002001' - I want to compare with each `SETTLEMENT_ID` from `t1`. How can I do this? Please provide some solution.

Further, the query is returning count in two rows i.e: count against two different ids right now. How can I add the result of two different ids to get the sum of these two rows returned by the sub-query?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: Is this the complete query? Because I think the outer `select` statement is not necessary. And where clause will compare each value in the column with the data which you want to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to compare against each Settlement_id from table PScData?.

From my understanding of the question, you might do a self join on the table PScData or use the below query.

This query will compare the settlement_id against all settlement_ids from the same table. I dont understand why you want to do this.

Please check the script and let me know if I get you wrong.

```
SELECT 
        SUM(Total_Males) [Total_males],  SETTLEMENT_ID,URI, _PARENT_AURI    
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             COUNT(t2.SEX) as Total_Males, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID, t1.URI, 
             t2._PARENT_AURI 
         FROM 
             PScData t1 
         INNER JOIN 
             PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
         WHERE 
             t1.SETTLEMENT_ID in (SELECT DISTINCT SETTLEMENT_ID FROM PScData)
             AND t2.SEX = '1'
         GROUP BY 
             t1.URI, t2._PARENT_AURI, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID) tmp
group by
     SETTLEMENT_ID,URI, _PARENT_AURI
```

Comment: yes your answer is correct. It can also be done like this in the where clause  " t1.SETTLEMENT_ID = SETTLEMENT_ID AND t2.SEX = '1' " . i just found .please help with the second part i.e: how to sum the values retrieved through count .thanks

Comment: Thanks for the comment Sadia. You might accept this as answer if the script helped you. Thanks again for the Upvote.

Comment: Let me know the know the field on which you would like to get the sum?.

Comment: In the query COUNT(t2.Sex) gives multiple values becoz of distinct ids i want to add that Count(t2.sex) result value into 1 answer

Comment: You are grouping by Settlement_ID , thatw as the reason it was showing the count based on Settlement ID. IF you remove settlement_id from the SELECT list and GROUP BY, you will receive the total count.

Comment: Please check the script now. Let me know if you face any errors.

Comment: no i want the sum against each individual id as there are multiple records against one id in my table so for similar ids i want a sum of total males against each id. i dont want the overall sum of the data

Answer (score 1):

A sub-query is void here. Just perform the join and filter out the settlements if you don't need all of them. But it is not clear from your question if you want to filter them out or just match them. For the purpose of matching use joins.

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.SEX) as Total_Males, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID, t1.URI, t2._PARENT_AURI 
FROM PScData t1 
    INNER JOIN PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
WHERE t2.SEX = '1'
GROUP BY t1.URI, t2._PARENT_AURI, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID
```

If you need to filter them out, you need to prepare the list of wanted settlements and use `IN` in the `WHERE` clause. You can use a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to spread out the list of wanted settlements and pass it in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH cteSettlements AS (
    SELECT SETLLEMENT_ID
    FROM PscData
    WHERE ? -- apply some criteria
)
SELECT COUNT(t2.SEX) as Total_Males, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID, t1.URI, t2._PARENT_AURI 
FROM PScData t1 
    INNER JOIN PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
WHERE t1.SETTLEMENT_ID IN cteSettlements AND t2.SEX = '1'
GROUP BY t1.URI, t2._PARENT_AURI, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID
```

As for the second question - *How can I add the result of two different ids to get the sum of these two rows*? - you need to play with the `GROUP BY` clause. As far as I understand, you actually don't need to group be `SETTLEMENT_ID` so just remove it from the `GROUP BY`. Just remember that you need to remove it from the `SELECT` list too.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the query the result can be retrieved and summed up like this:

```
SELECT Total_Males, SETTLEMENT_ID
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(t2.SEX) as Total_Males, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 
    FROM PScData t1  
        INNER JOIN PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
    WHERE t1.SETTLEMENT_ID in (SELECT DISTINCT SETTLEMENT_ID FROM PScData)
      AND t2.SEX = '1'
    GROUP BY t1.SETTLEMENT_ID
) tmp
```

Comment: Hi Sadia. Thansk for sharing this answer. I will certainly upvote this asap, once my voting balance is updated.

Comment: Again, the subquery is void. In this case, actually, the outer query is void. You'll get the same result by executing just the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try With ,

```
Select 
Total_Males, SETTLEMENT_ID , URI, _PARENT_AURI    
from
(Select 
COUNT(t2.SEX) as Total_Males ,t1.SETTLEMENT_ID  , t1.URI, t2._PARENT_AURI    
from 
PScData t1 
INNER JOIN 
PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
 where
  t1.SETTLEMENT_ID in (SELECT DISTINCT SETTLEMENT_ID FROM PScData)
  AND t2.SEX = '1'
 Group By 
t1.SETTLEMENT_ID ) tmp
```